# How to loop NSDictionary obtained from JSON?

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

How can i loop through the following dictionary obtained from JSON? How can i loop to get only the id 0001, 0002?

```
{
    0001 = {
      userName = "a";
      photo = "";
    };
    0002 = {
      userName = "b";
      photo = "";
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer. I already tried with the following code but it is giving all the data.
Because the json i got is in the worng format.

```
    for (NSString *key in Dict) {}
```

Comment: The keys in a `NSDictionary` do not have to be of type `NSString`, since in your example the keys will be `NSNumbers`

Answer (score 3):

You loop thru the `NSDictionary` keys:

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKey];

for (id *key in keys ) {
    NSDictionary *userPhoto = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    // here you can either parse the object to a custom class
    // or just add it to an array.
}
```

Or use the [fast enumeration](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) directly on the `NSDictionary`:

```
for (id *key in dictionary ) {
    NSDictionary *userPhoto = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    // here you can either parse the object to a custom class
    // or just add it to an array.
}
```

Per key you can retrieve the object.

or use the [`enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // Here you can access the object and key directly.
}
```

Comment: *"there is no real way to loop thru a NSDictionary"* - That's not true. `for (NSString *key in dict)` *does* enumerate the dictionary keys, so you don't need `allKeys`. And there is `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way...

**Get all keys**

```
NSArray *a=[yourDictionary allKeys];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
```

Try this. You will get all keys in an array. And then you can get them in `NSString` accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using the [`enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock%3a) api to enumerate the keys and objects,

Usage is pretty simple,

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value:%@",key,obj);
    if([key isEqualToString:@"0001"]) {
        //Do something
    }
    // etc.
}];
```

Hope that helps!